# $_SESSION variables not transferring from page to page

Tags: php, session

If I write the following code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']='daniel';
```

the variable stays fine as long as I'm on the page on which it was created, and the second I try to call `$_SESSION['user_id']` from another page, I don't get a response.
Can anyone tell me what mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be using `session_start()` on **every** page you want to use sessions on.

Comment: @daniel - yes. It calls up the session from storage.

Comment: yes. you should really read the section about sessions in the manual before starting to code.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic: Better make your anwer a statement rather thant a question.

Answer (score 4):

As long as:

- You are doing [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/function.session-start) on the other page. **Note:** you don't make this call once. You do it on every page that wants to access the session information;
- The other page can see your cookie from this site (ie sufficiently similar domain); and
- The other page is running on the same server.

then it can see it. Construct a simple test case and verify this and then work out why what you're doing is different.

Answer (score 1):

You must have `session_start()` on **every page**

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the PHPSESSID cookie is actually being set, and that no headers / content have been sent before you call session_start()